# Patching a parent class

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking

I'm having trouble getting a parent class mocked with `mock.patch`.

Here's a test case:

In `parent.py`:

```
import mock

class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        print("Original recipe")
```

In `child.py`:

```
from parent import Parent

class Child(Parent):
    def foo(self):
        print('Parent is {}'.format(Parent))
```

In `test.py`:

```
import mock

from child import Child

c = Child()  # expect 'Original recipe'
c.foo()

with mock.patch('child.Parent'):
    c = Child() # expect silence
    c.foo()
```

When I run `test.py` I expect to get:

```
Original recipe
Parent is <class 'parent.Parent'>
Parent is <MagicMock name='Parent' id='4325705712'>
```

but instead I get:

```
Original recipe
Parent is <class 'parent.Parent'>
Original recipe
Parent is <MagicMock name='Parent' id='4325705712'>
```

So the patch is happening (from the "Parent is" statement) but not for the class inheritance. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not patching the `Parent` class, you are patching the `child` module, changing its `Parent` attribute to a mock. This does not change `Child` at all, because it still uses the old `Parent` class as base class.

In Python 3, you can instead patch `Child.__bases__` to change the base class at runtime. This come with its weirdnesses, of course.

## Additional details

Python has no "variables", only names bound to specific objects in memory. Changing those names bindings (e.g. patching the scope they are contained it with `mock.patch` or `setattr`) has absolutely no effect on previous uses of these bindings.

This means that although you do patch the `Parent` attribute of the `child` module, replacing it by a `Mock`, as the module has already loaded, the class is already defined with the old target of the `Parent` attribute, which is, the original `Parent` class.

## Other ways to test `Child` instances

### As if `Parent` as external

```
with mock.patch('child.Child.method_that_calls_method_on_parent'):
    ...
```

If you want to isolate and mock method on `Parent` when testing instances of `Child`, you could make the calls to `Parent` sit in dedicated methods (and then patch these methods), as you'd do test external classes.

### Patching methods on `Parent`

If you know in advance which methods of `Parent` you'll need to patch, you can just imply patch the methods on `Parent`.

```
with mock.patch('parent.Parent.method'):
    ...
```

This will mutate the value of the `Parent` attribute (which is the same for the `child` and `parent` modules, as `child` imports `Parent` from `parent`), instead of modifying which objects the `Parent` attribute points to in a particular module as you were doing before.

### Making `Parent` behave like a `Mock`

```
with mock.patch('parent.Parent.__getattribute__'):
    ...
```

This is the most close to the intent of your original code. It relies on changing the way Python gets attributes from the `Parent` class, effectively patching all of its possible attributes.

The disadvantage with this is that you'd get a mock even for non-existing attributes, but that was the case with your original approach as well. This can be overcome by replacing `__getattribute__` with a wrapper that returns a mock only for found attributes :

```
def _getmock(self, name):
    value = object.__getattribute__(self, name)
    return Mock(value)
_original = getattr(parent.Parent, '__getattribute__')
setattr(parent.Parent, '__getattribute__', _getmock)
try:
    ...
finally:
    setattr(parent.Parent, '__getattribute__', _original)
```

(Your test suite probably provides a way to temporarily patch `_getmock` as `parent.Parent.__getattribute__`, as `mock.patch` does, which would make this simpler.)

This can be further customized to specify the type and parameters of the mock created depending on the attribute name (`name` in `_getmock`) or value (`value` in `_getmock`), or making it so that the same mock is returned for when the same attribute name is accessed multiple times.

Comment: Can you explain why base class of Chlid is the original Parent and not the mock? Is it because the class is derived during compile time? 

I got something working as expected with `__bases__`, but ugh. Is there no more reasonable way to do this sort of thing?

Comment: When you create the `Child` class (at the runtime of module `child`), you use the current value of the `Parent` attribute as base class. There are no variables in Python, only names that reference objects. If you change which objects a name points to, you are not changing that object. I think the correct way to do this would be to not mock the class, but only its instances (using a mock specification to tie it to the class, for example).

Comment: I have never found "Python has no variables" to be helpful. In "x = 1", x is a variable.  I do find it helpful to explain that Python variables work by having names refer to values (objects).

Comment: I should have been more specific, I meant "no variables defined at compile-time". It's true that this way of saying it is confusing to many.