# pytest @patch does not work for mocking the whole class (all the methods of the class) but works for mocking individual methods of the class

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-mock, pytest-mock-patch

I have two classes like below:

in parent.py:

```
class TestClassParent(ABC):
    def test_method(self):
        print('the method TestMethod is called')
        return True
```

in child.py:

```
from src.scripts.parent import TestClassParent
class TestClassChild(TestClassParent):
    custom_vars = [1, 2, 3]
```

I have a test class for child.py called, child_test.py like this:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch
from src.scripts.child import TestClassChild
class ChildTest(TestCase):
    @patch('src.scripts.child.TestClassParent', autospec=True)
    def test(self, mock_parent_class):
        mock_parent_class.return_value.test_method.return_value = False
        i = TestClassChild()
        a = i.test_method()
        assert a is False
```

Looks like the patch `@patch('src.scripts.child.TestClassParent', autospec=True)` didn't work and when `a = i.test_method()` is executed, the actual implementation is run.

However mocking an individual methods of the `TestClassParent` works as expected for example if I change the implementation like below, it works fine:

```
@patch('src.scripts.child.TestClassParent.test_method', autospec=True)
    def test(self, mock_method):
        mock_method.return_value = False
        i = TestClassChild()
        a = i.test_method()
        assert a is False
```

I also read from [pytest - Patching a class does not work, calls class instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55597811/pytest-patching-a-class-does-not-work-calls-class-instead) that I should mock the class where it's used not where it's defined and I did it exactly like that, the `TestClassParent` was used inside `TestClassChild` so I mocked where it's used: `@patch('src.scripts.child.TestClassParent')` but no luck.
I even mocked both `TestClassChild` and `TestClassParent` (both the usage and definition) still no luck and also removed `autospec=True` but again no luck.

Any ideas ??

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be assuming an incorrect resolution order.

The modules are imported and therefore the class relationships defined ***before*** the patch ever occurs.

What you're targeting by mocking all methods of a parent class that propagate through children can probably be done through meta programming, although it would likely be sort of hacky -- so I wouldn't recommend it.

Another solution could be to alter the classes to utilize dependency injection, but if it were me, I would simply mock the instances as needed and call it a day.

This link may provide further clarification -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/38928265/13261176

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
class ChildTest(TestCase):
    def test(self) -> None:
        with patch.object(TestClassChild, "my_test_method", return_value=False) as m:
            i = TestClassChild()
            a = i.my_test_method()
            assert a is False
        assert m.called
```

also notice the you may need to rename your method otherwise `pytest` will collect it and issue a `PytestReturnNotNoneWarning`.

Comment: Like I said in the description, mocking a single method of the `TestClassChild` is already working fine. I want to mock the whole class without having to mocking all its methods one by one.